# Drag and drop inside an area which is not existent, drop it between lines

Tags: python, selenium, automated-tests

I have a web application with grids and elements inside. I use Selenium with Python to automate tasks and I would like to drag and drop an element inside this grid but the grid doesn't have an area, it is just lines.
There is a picture of the div where the lines are located:

[image]

My question is how can I drag and drop an element inside this grid(square) made by lines ?

Something like that :
[image]

Comment: Compute the distance to the desired location from the element and use `drag_and_drop_by_offset` https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html#selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains.drag_and_drop_by_offset

Comment: Thanks I am going to check that right now.

Comment: It works but, do you know how can I get the size of it, because I need to check if the size of the element == size of the box

Comment: `line.location` is (x, y) pixel location of the line, and `element.rect` is the size and location of the element. You can get the location of all four lines and compute the square size and compare to the size of the element that you get from `rect`.